# How can I rotate an equation and do a density plot?

Tags: plotting

I have an equation: (1 + (0.0161591 + 0.132143 x - 0.0145471 x^2 +
0.0155075 x^3)^2)^(3/2)/(0.132143 - 0.0290943 x + 0.0465225 x^2). But I want to rotate it (keeping the value in 0) and get something like in the image. Then I want to do a density plot.

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want, but if you wish, you can experiment with this code which uses a RotationTransform to rotate your plot by Pi/4:

```
rotationF[x_, y_, \[Gamma]_] := RotationTransform[\[Gamma]][{x, y}]
rotationF[{x_, y_}, \[Gamma]_] := RotationTransform[\[Gamma]][{x, y}];
myF[x_] := (1 + (0.0161591 + 0.132143 x - 0.0145471 x^2 + 
        0.0155075 x^3)^2)^(3/2)/(0.132143 - 0.0290943 x + 
    0.0465225 x^2)
p1 = Plot[myF[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red];
myAngle = -Pi/4;
p2 = ParametricPlot[rotationF[{x, myF[x]}, myAngle], {x, -5, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 15]
```

[image]